# ¿Cómo obtener ref de componente tres niveles superior para events Scroll?

Tags: reactjs

Este el ejemplo de la librería:

```
<div style="height:700px;overflow:auto;" ref={(ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref}>
<div>
    <InfiniteScroll
        pageStart={0}
        loadMore={loadFunc}
        hasMore={true || false}
        loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
        useWindow={false}
        getScrollParent={() => this.scrollParentRef}
    >
        {items}
    </InfiniteScroll>
</div>
```

necesito  `ref={(ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref` se de un componente padre que esta mucho mas arriba, intente mandarlo por props y no funciona, dice que no es una función, también la mande por redux como un estado global y tampoco funciona

```
class AppEmpty extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.setReferences(this.scrollParentRef);
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const isActive = this.props.isActive;

    return (
      <div className="App">

        <NavBar/>

        <MenuRight/>

        <div id="content"
          className={isActive ? "content_enable": ""}
          style={this.props.menuRight.styleContent}
          ref={ (ref) => this.scrollParentRef = ref }
        >
          <FlashMessages/>
          {children}
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

AppEmpty.protoTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
};

function mapsStateToProps(state){
  return {
    menuRight: state.menuRight,
    isActive: state.isActive,
  };


}

export default connect (mapsStateToProps, {setReferences})(AppEmpty);
```

Este es lo dice la librería para establecer el padre:

> getScrollParent   Function        Override method to return a different
>   scroll listener if it's not the immediate parent of InfiniteScroll.

¿Alguien me puede sugerir una manera de pasar esa referencia de una forma fácil al componente de infiniteScroll?

Comment: Creo que faltan los demás componentes que están involucrados y también estaría bueno que pusieras para que lo quieres utilizar.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467146/what-is-the-different-between-the-ref-callback-and-the-ref-myinput-in-reac) la cosa es que no he entendido como pasar el ref calback por props o redux para poder referenciar cualquier componente!

Answer (score 0):

Despues de probar de todo, me di cuenta que puedo pasar como una refs utilizando document.getElementById('id_compmente_a_referenciar') :(

Content-> compomente_base -> form_busqueda, Tables -> InfiniteScroll(Refs_Content).

```
<div>
    <InfiniteScroll
        pageStart={0}
        loadMore={loadFunc}
        hasMore={true || false}
        loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
        useWindow={false}
        getScrollParent={ () => document.getElementById('content') }
    >
        {items}
    </InfiniteScroll>
</div>
```

Es muy útil cuando el componente hijo pide como parámetro la refs del componente padre que esta muchísimos niveles a arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tendrías que crear el `ref` en el padre que deseas usarlo y pasarlo como `props` al hijo donde lo vas a usar.

Esto en las versiones menor a la 16.8 no era posible, pero en la versión actual viene una nueva función en la api; dicha función se llama `forwardRef`. Lo que nos permite esta función poder pasar un `ref` como props y ser usado en el padre que se creó.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Tomando tu ejemplo como caso. Esto sería así (He eliminado ciertas líneas de código para simplificar el ejemplo):

```js
import React, {createRef} from 'react';

class AppEmpty extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.scrollParentRef = createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.scrollParentRef);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlashMessages ref={this.scrollParentRef}/>
    );
  }
}

export default AppEmpty;
```

FlashMessages

```js
import React, {forwardRef} from 'react';

// Eso no es necesario que sea un stateless. Puede ser un statefull también
const FlashMessages = props => (
  <div ref={props.forwardedRef}>
  {/* algún mensaje */}
  </div>
);

export default forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <FlashMessages {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />
));
```

De esta forma, desde el Padre (**AppEmpty**) podrás acceder al `ref` que contiene el hijo (**FlashMessages**)

Comment: Puedes dar un ejemplo cobre tu solución?? no solo ayudara al OP sino a todos los interesados futuros... te dejo este enlace: [answer] para mas información...